# HTML help --hidding a button

Tags: html

I need help with my HTML styling.

here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="hidden" style="display: none;">
    <label>URL:</label>
    <input type="text" name="url" size="50"/><br/>
    <input type="button" id="button2" value="Update"/> <br/>
</div>
<input type="button" id="button1" value ="Get Info" 
    onclick="document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = '';" size="25"/>
```

As you can see, all the elements that are inside `<div></div>` will be displayed upon clicking `button1` (they are hidden initially).

What I want is that when `button1` is clicked in addition to all the other fields (including button2) being displayed, `button1` to be hidden.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
onclick="document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = '';"
```

to

```
onclick="document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = ''; this.style.display = 'none'"
```

You can see this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/nayish/sJ5RR/.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `''` change it to `'Block'`

so:

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value ="Get Info"
onclick="document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = 'Block';" size="25"/>
```

But the best way will be to externalize your script so you can do more stuff without cluttering your html

```
var btn = document.getElementById('button1');
btn.onclick = function () {
   // all the stuff you want to do 
   document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = "block";
   this.style.display = "none";
   ... more stuff ...
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. It should be a comment. There is nothing wrong with either solution (`''` or `'block'`). @Ross: When you set display to empty string, it gets defaulted to `block`. (`div`s are block level elements) If you set it to `block` it is more clear, but you may decide you want to set it to `''` if you want it to also work for `span` which is an `inline` element or for `tr` which might be `table-row` or `block` depending on the browser.